# Consulta a MySql recurriendo a indices

Tags: mysql

tengo una duda que no puedo resolver con Mysql:
Como puedo hacer la consulta en este caso para obtener a traves del id_invitado el nombre del cliente y el nombre de la empresa???
Espero ayuda ya que estoy muy enredado con esto.
Gracias!!
Jose
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: utiliza join's para agregar los campos que requieres en tu consulta

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega la consulta que has intentado. De esa forma podremos saber donde puede estar el error que has cometido

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
E.Empresa_descrip AS EMPRESA,
C.cliente_nombre AS NOMBRE
FROM Invitacion I
INNER JOIN Clientes C ON I.Id_Cliente = C.cliente_id
INNER JOIN Empresa E ON C.empresa_id = E.Empresa_id
WHERE I.Id_Invitado = 'IdInvitado' AND C.Cliente_nombre = 'NombreCliente'
```

Debes encadenar con JOIN las tablas involucradas en cada salto. Date cuenta que estoy enlazando INVITACION con CLIENTES y CLIENTES con EMPRESA.

---

Puedes leer más [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) sobre el uso de joins

Comment: Ya está, agregué lo que sugeriste

Comment: Sería bueno agregar el filtro por el nombre de empresa, que es lo que @Jose Martinez esta pdieiendo ademas del id de invitado

Comment: Buena sugerencia Levi, no caché bien lo que quería, pero ya agregué esa parte.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! por la rapida respuesta, lo revisare y les cuento , porque como soy novato, me enredo con la E y la C, suopngo que C es un alias de Clientes y E alias de empresa, pero no se si debo definir antes los alias o esta implicito en la misma consulta. Lo tratare de ejecutar y les comento, de verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: Es correcto, las letras mayúsculas son un alias de la tabla, puedes también llamar directamente a la tabla sin poner alias. Si te sirvió la respuesta, no dudes en marcala como correcta en la palomita de tu lado izquierdo.

Comment: Exacto, pero los alias son convencionales en este caso C para Clientes, E para Empresas e I para Invitacion, puedes aprender sobre alias [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: Estimados, no me funciono, me devuelve vacio. Ademas, mi idea era que el where fuese indicando solo el id_invitado y no Id_inivtado + NombreCliente. Osea, en resumen, tener el dato del id_invitado y que me devuelva el nombre de la persona y la empresa. De verdad agradezco y aprecio mucho su buena voluntad. Saludos! Jose

Comment: Juegan muchas variantes aquí José, la estructura de la tabla, las Foreign Keys de las tablas, los parámetros que le pasas a la query... Necesitaríamos ver tu tabla para poder ayudarte.

Comment: hay una manera de pasarles las tablas para que lo revisen?
PLISS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes generar con joins lo que informas como lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Tabla Regiones

IdRegion
Region
----------------------

Tabla Provincias


Idprovincia
Provincia
Idregion(FK)
----------------------


Tabla Comunas

Idcomuna
Comuna
provincia (FK)
-----------------------

    SELECT c.comuna, p.provincia, r.region FROM Comunas c 
INNER JOIN Provincias p (ON c.idprovincia= p.idprovincia)
INNER JOIN Regiones r (ON r.IdRegion = p.IdRegion)
```

con cada Join tu agregas gracias a los alias los campos que requieres de las tablas. Saludos, espero te sea de utilidad. Ahora bien con la finalidad de dar rpta a las tablas que mencionas quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT 
   c.cliente_nombre AS NombreCliente,
   e.Empresa_descrip AS DescripcionEmpresa 
FROM Invitacion i
INNER JOIN Clientes c (ON i.Id_Cliente = c.cliente_id)
INNER JOIN empresa e (ON c.empresa_id = e.Empresa_id)
WHERE i.Id_invitado = 'TuIdInvitado';
```

Answer (score 1):

bueno, no encontre otra forma de subir una imagen para que vean el formato de las tablas, trabajo en Mysql.
Espero que se clarifique mas la idea. Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La estructura de tus tablas es inconsistente. Los campos y los nombres de las tablas son muy distintas del código que te pasé, por obvias razones no jalará. Ahora, si vas a hacer una llave foránea, el tipo y longitud debe ser el mismo tanto del Primary Key como del Foreign Key. Debes corregir la estructura de tu tabla, así no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: @Alberto Siurob , Tienes toda la razón , repare eso . las buenas practicas tienen su sentido y yo me las salte. Quedaron todas las llaves con el tipo de dato INT y de largo 5. Existe una forma de mandarle las tablas?

Comment: Ejecuta esta consulta sql en tu phpmyadmin: DESCRIBE empresa_entidad, esa instrucción te trae la estructura de la tabla, haces lo mismo con las otras dos y cuando tengas los 3 resultados, editas esta respuesta y pones lo que tienes actualmente